# what is client property of knexfile.js

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

In **knex** [documentation](https://knexjs.org/#knexfile) of configuration of `knexfile.js` for PostgreSQL, they have a property called `client`, which looks this way:

```
...
client: 'pg'
...
```

However, going through some other projects that utilize PostgreSQL I noticed that they have a different value there, which looks this way:

```
...
client: 'postgresql'
...
```

Does this string correspond to the name of some sort of **command line tool** that is being used with the project or I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql is based on a server-client model as described in '[Architectural Fundamentals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-arch.html)'

**psql** is the standard cli client of postgres as mentioned here in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html).

A client may as well be a GUI such as pg-admin, or a node-package such as '[pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg)' - here's a [list](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients#CLI_Clients).

The client parameter is required and determines which **client adapter** will be used with the library.

You should also read the docs of '[Server Setup and Operation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime.html)'

To initialize the library you can do the following (in this case on localhost):

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    user : 'your_database_user',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test'
  }
})
```

The standard user of the client deamon ist 'postgres' - which you can use of course, but its highly advisable to create a new user as stated in the docs and/or apply a password to the standard user 'postgres'.

On Debian stretch i.E.:

```
# su - postgres
$ psql -d template1 -c "ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'SecretPasswordHere';"
```

Make sure you delete the command line history so nobody can read out your pwd:

```
rm ~/.psql_history
```

Now you can add a new user (i.E. foobar) on the system and for postgres

```
# adduser foobar
```

and

```
# su - postgres
$ createuser --pwprompt --interactive foobar
```

Lets look at the following setup:

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: 'xyz',
    connection: { user: 'foobar', database: 'my_app' }
  },
 production: { client: 'abc', connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL }
 };
```

This basically tells us the following:

In dev - use the client *xyz* to connect to postgresqls database *my_app* with the user *foobar* (in this case without pwd)

In prod - retrieve the globalenv the url of the db-server is set to and connect via the client *abc*

Here's an example how node's pg-client package opens a connection pool:

```
const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'foobar',
    host: 'someUrl',
    database: 'someDataBaseName',
    password: 'somePWD',
    port: 5432,
})
```

If you could clarify or elaborate your setup or what you like to achieve a little more i could give you some more detailed info - but i hope that helped anyways..